# how to start another fuction in java script and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to call another function after an ajax function finishes. After successful registration of a user, I want to have a callback function, but when I try, my sign up function stops working:

```
function signUp(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#register").click(function() {
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            var cpassword = $("#cpassword").val();

            if (name == '' || email == '' || password == '' || cpassword == '') {
                alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
            } else if ((password.length) < 8) {
                alert("Password should atleast 8 character in length...!!!!!!");
            } else if (!(password).match(cpassword)) {
                alert("Your passwords don't match. Try again?");
            } else {
                $.post("register.php", {
                    name1: name,
                    email1: email,
                    password1: password
                }, function(data) {
                    if (data == 'You have Successfully Registered.....') {
                        $("form")[0].reset();
                    }
                    alert(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** your `$(document).ready(function()..` shouldn't be inside another function, because this way it will only get called when that function is called, and problably that is not what you intended, as i don't know how you use signUp() function i can't really tell.

You can use this way of making ajax request

```
function signUp(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#register").click(function() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var cpassword = $("#cpassword").val();

        if (name == '' || email == '' || password == '' || cpassword == '') {
            alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
        } else if ((password.length) < 8) {
            alert("Password should atleast 8 character in length...!!!!!!");
        } else if (!(password).match(cpassword)) {
            alert("Your passwords don't match. Try again?");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "http://localhost:5000/your/endpoint",
                    data: {
                        name1: name,
                        email1: email,
                        password1: password
                    },
                    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                        // function called when it has succeeded 
                        // Do what you want here in case of success
                        // The best way to do this should be used with statusCode because basically you
                        // only want to know that your post was OK.

                    },
                    statusCode: {
                        // Add more status code if you want to do something for each
                        200: function(){
                             $("form")[0].reset();
                             alert('You have Successfully Registered.....');
                        },
                        500: function(){
                            // In case of server error you should do something also
                        }
                    }
                    error: function(xhr, msg, err){
                        // Function called when error happens
                    }
            })

        }
    });
});
```

}

You can even define functions to be called when a given status code is given as response, you can find the complete reference on [http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/](http://JQuery%20AJAX)

Comment: i have edited so it contains also your code, test it, and your endpoint in the backend server must allow POST requests for the chosen endpoint (url) and respond with the right status code

Comment: on clicking register button nothing happen

Comment: see my edit, you shouldn't be wrapping you code inside signUp() functionm but it depends how you are using it

Comment: can you give me the full details of the error and the complete usage of this function, your full script ?